# How to match 2 out of "1,2,7,9,13,3,10,4,21,6,12" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm not familiar with regex in MySQL.

Comment: What do you want to match? The digit "2" or two numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIKE '%,2,%'` to match in the middle, `LIKE '2,%'` to match at start, `LIKE '%,2'` to match at end and to exact match, you can use `= '2'`

**UPDATE**: To work all cases, you could use OR, `X LIKE '%,2,%' OR X LIKE '2,%' OR X LIKE '%,2' OR X='2'`

Answer (score 8):

For testing if the value exists in the string you can use

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET(15, '1,2,15,4,5,6');
+---------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET(15, '1,2,15,4,5,6') |
+---------------------------------+
|                               3 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and test it for greater than 0 (0 is returned if no match is found).

Answer (score 2):

What problem are you *really* trying to solve, here, though? This smells like bad design.

(I don't see any *comment* box, perhaps due to lack of rep --- therefore posted as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '1,2,7,9,13,3,10,4,21,6,12' REGEXP '(^2$)|(^2,)|(,2,)|(,2$)' AS matches
```

It can probably be fine tuned but it should work.

*P.S. Please don't use the subject to write the whole question*

Comment: not sure about MySQL, but `\b2\b` can work well here. Also, please don't use the **answer** to *comment* on the question, unless it is relevant.